# JavaScript function that works like location.pathname but without returning the folders before root

Tags: javascript

I am looking for a JavaScript function that will return the path from the root of the current file.

I have come across location.pathname and that gives me what I need but with the path from volumes to the root included. For example, location.pathname would return:

```
/volumes/Macintosh%20HD/Users/me/Github/root/folder1/folder2/folder3/index.html
```

I want something that will return only the following:

```
/folder1/folder2/folder3/index.html
```

Comment: How is your current file supposed to know the root? For now root seems arbitrarily defined. What if the folder level `Github` was your root?

Comment: Oh duh. Obviously. I'll just write a function that cuts off everything before the root name

Comment: Now you are making sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following script, search for the 'root' part in a given string and performing string concatenation (including everything after root) in order to return a partial path as you have requested.

```js
function findPath(input) {
  // let's splits in parts our input string
  var parts = input.split('/'),
      result = '/',
      canSave = false;
  // for each part
  parts.forEach(function(item) {
    // if we detect a root part
    if (item === 'root') {
      // start concatenation from next part
      canSave = true;
      return;
    }
    if (canSave) {
      // concatenate part in the final result
      result += item;
      result += '/';
    }
  });
  // removing last slash
  return result = result.slice(0, -1);
}

var input = '/volumes/Macintosh%20HD/Users/me/Github/root/folder1/folder2/folder3/index.html',
output = findPath(input)

console.log(output);
```

In alternative if you do not like to use `split()` when returning from the function:
https://jsfiddle.net/wns8jbp5/